# Vagrant create base box

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

***SO*** many articles on this that do not work or cannot revert misconfigs. Perhaps deleting all Boxes and starting again would help but Vagrant says they cannot be found / destroyed even after identifying using things like

```
vagrant box list
```

I am trying to acheive such a simple requirement - use Ubuntu server LTS, setup Nginx, PHP, MySQL.
Config Nginx to display a test HTML and PHPinfo.php page.

Package that box so I can reuse an existing web dev VM that is setup and working.

Vagrant continually ignores new packaged box and loads 'default' despite editing Vagrantfile.

I have not done anything funky, just trying to create a base box from official ubuntu/xenial64 before I waste another 2 days where Vagrant packages without private/public keys and becomes useless.

Current sources are as below but this is so poorly documented regarding packaging a re-usable box that I am beginning to think Vagrant is unusable.

```
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one

#minimise and delete junk
sudo apt-get clean;
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/EMPTY bs=1M;
sudo rm -f /EMPTY;
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit;

#package it
vagrant package --output lnmp_1604_70.box

#add box
vagrant box add lnmp_1604_70_v01 lnmp_1604_70.box

vagrant init lnmp_1604_70_v01

# IMPORTANT - do this before first vagrant up

config.vm.box = "lnmp_1604_70_v01"
config.ssh.insert_key = false;# in Vagrantfile

# It will keep the insecure key in place while prepping your VM for packaging
# If the key has already been replaced you can restore the default one by editing "~vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys" and replacing it with # the insecure public key at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub
```

Vagrant 1.9.8

Answer (score 0):

The procedure described at [How to Create a Vagrant Base Box from an Existing One](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one) works perfectly on my box.

I think that after

```
vagrant box add lnmp_1604_70_v01 lnmp_1604_70.box
```

you have to run

```
vagrant init lnmp_1604_70_v01
```

instead of, as you wrote in your question,

```
vagrant init lnmp_1604_70
```

Comment: vagrant init lnmp_1604_70_v01 was the actual statement run, corrected Question, well spotted tho

Comment: What Vagrant version are you ising?

Comment: Are you using Virtualbox as provider? Because "vagrant package" works only with Virtualbox and Hyper-V. Instead of Vagrant, you can try Packer to build machine image, then turn the image to Vagrantbox adding a post-processor to Packer build template. See https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/vagrant.html . Hope it helps.